# Dynamic global variable in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to put a dynamic title on my website so here it is.

```
class Survey extends MY_Controller {

   public $my_title;

   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Survey_model');
     $this->my_title = ""; //setting to blank
   }

   public function survey_form(){
     $this->data['title']    = $this->my_title; //display the title
     $this->middle       = 'Survey_view';
     $this->layout();
   }

   public function validate_stub($survey_code){
     $data          = $this->Survey_model->get_questions($survey_code);
     $this->my_title    = $this->Survey_model->get_quest_title($survey_code); //getting from database title 

     $this->session->set_userdata('stub_data', $data);
     redirect('Survey/survey_form');
   }
}
```

The first to trigger is the validate_stub function then i would like to pass the return of get_quest_title to global variable $my_title then pass it to the survey_form function. In this case $this->my_title is blank, how can i pass the title from db then put into the global variable then pass to the view. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand why you use `redirect` in `validate_stub()`. You can call the `survey_form` function straight here is the code:

```
class Survey extends MY_Controller {

   public $my_title;

   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Survey_model');
     $this->my_title = ""; //setting to blank
   }

   public function survey_form(){
     $grab_title = $this->session->userdata('my_title');
     if(isset($grab_title) && $grab_title != "") {
         $this->data['title']    = $grab_title;
     }else {
         //do some checks here and add something default
         $this->data['title']    = $this->my_title;             
     }
     $this->middle       = 'Survey_view';
     $this->layout();
   }

   public function validate_stub($survey_code){
     $data          = $this->Survey_model->get_questions($survey_code);
     $this->my_title    = $this->Survey_model->get_quest_title($survey_code); //getting from database title 

     $this->session->set_userdata('stub_data', $data);
     $this->session->set_userdata('my_title', $this->my_title);
     redirect('Survey/survey_form');
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks! btw coz it's a form action if i put $this->survey_form() the link will be /validate_stub, i want it as /survey_form

Comment: So what's the use of validate_stub() ? You can copy/paste the code from validate_stub() to survey_form() and use that function instead. Or you should consider using form_validation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: i have a long validation logic there that's why i separated the validation

Comment: In order not to change your logic, you can pass the title through session. Check edit.

Comment: O my god i didn't think that gosh Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad i could helped :)